# Checkbox values in form update doesn´t work

Tags: yii2

I have one little problem with checkboxes in yii. I have modal popup, where i have form for update.
Here is my controller:

```
public function actionUpdateroomrow(){
      $model = Rooms::findOne($_POST['id']);
      $model -> room_number_of_people = $_POST['room_number_of_people'];
      $model -> room_name = $_POST['room_name'];
      if(isset($_POST['room_air_conditioning']))
      $model -> room_air_conditioning = $_POST['room_air_conditioning'];
      else $model -> room_air_conditioning = false;
      $model->update();


      if (isset ($_POST['room_multimedia_id'])){
         foreach($_POST['room_multimedia_id'] as $key => $value){
            $model2 = RoomMultimediaData::findOne($value);
            $model2 -> room_multimedia_data_value = $key;
      var_dump($model2 -> errors); 
    }
 }

      $this->redirect('index');
 }
```

Where is problem? In this row.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <?php foreach($room_multimedia as $rm){ ?> 
 <label><?= $rm->room_multimedia_title ?></label><input type="checkbox" name="room_multimedia_id[<?= $rm->Checkmultimediadata($room->room_id,$rm->room_multimedia_id)->room_multimedia_data_id ?>]" value="<?= $rm->room_multimedia_id ?>"/>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

This is row from update formular and im not really sure, where i failed.
In RoomMultimedia.php, modul i have this:

```
public function Checkmultimediadata($room_id,$room_multimedia){

        return RoomMultimediaData::find()->where('room_id='.$room_id.' and room_multimedia_id='.$room_multimedia.'')->one();
    }
```

Warning from yii:

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

Creating default object from empty value
$model2 -> room_multimedia_data_value = $key;
```

Can you help me solve this?
Thank you all! :)

Comment: you need to use `checked` attribute for checkbox.

Comment: May be ` $model2 = RoomMultimediaData::findOne($value);` returning null value in `$model2`